# What is the correct way to declare and use MarisDB user defined variables?

Tags: mariadb

I'm using MariaDB version 10.3.28-MariaDB-cll-lve

This site https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/ says

> User-defined variables names must be preceded by a single at character (@)

That's what I usually do but recently I was rushing, forgot the '@ and wrote the following function which seems to work fine without the variables having '@' at the front.

So is having a '@' in front of a user defined variable a firm requirement or not?

If it is, why does my function work correctly without it?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  FUNCTION get_next_redacted_member_id() RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
       DECLARE result INT SIGNED;
       DECLARE lastid INT;
       INSERT INTO redacted_member_id ( date_used) VALUES ( NOW() ); 
       SET lastid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() );
       SET result =  -1 * lastid ;
       RETURN result;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: the use of user defined variables with @ will some day be obsolze, but i still can't understand how we can get rid of them completely, as we need them for prepared statements. it is a good way to see lokal defined variables if you markl them diffrently from colum names

Comment: Yes, I can see its a good idea. But it looks like it's no longer enforced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference ist that you can use DECALRE ony in stored function and procedzres

> DECLARE var_name

> This statement is used to declare local variables within stored programs.

see [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/declare-variable/)

> User-Defined Variables

> User-defined variables are variables which can be created by the user and exist in the session.

see [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/)

Which means every user defined variable is accessible every where(in a session) not only in a stored procedure/function. So you set your user defined Variable in a stored procudure, you can get the value eve after the stored procedure ends. That is very helpful for debugging such procedures/functions.

Also when you `DECLARE` a variable, you set also its data type and size.

With user defined MysQL decides what it needs when You `SET @a = 123455`

Comment: The 'main difference' between what?  My questions was why the documentation says we must proceed the variable name with '@' but my function seems to indicate that is not true. Are you saying that variables without the @ symbol act differently to those with it?

Comment: no, DECLARE set the datatype and SET @a mysql check which daRARYPE FILTS: the scope od DECLARE is the function or procidure and @a has the complete session

Comment: So are you saying that the scope of `DECLARE myvar INT` (without a'@' symbol) is just the function but the scope of `DECLARE @myvar INT` (with a @ symbol) is the entire session?

Comment: you can't declare a @myvar

Comment: ah. ok, i understand. answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   SET lastid = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() );
   SET result =  -1 * lastid ;
   RETURN result;
```

with

```
   SELECT -LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

and toss the two declarations.

If you have a more complex case, bring it on.